# How to I make a table that live updates new data entries/deletes without refresh in Spring/HTML?

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring, real-time-updates

Essentially I am working on a system where data entries are fed into a Java back-end and presented on a UI front-end (HTML). So far it works fine, however the last step I need to do is have it update the date table showing what's entering/exiting the system in real time. I am a complete beginner to this type of full-stack development so I am not exactly sure where to start. I've looked into php/javascrip/ajax/jquery but don't even know where to start yet and would appreciate some direction.

Summary:
Java Back-end has data being fed into it over time
HTML/ThymeLeaf front-end being used to display data (but not in real time, manual refreshing of page)
I want to be able to display the contents in real-time without having to refresh the page.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what you want to do exactly, you could technically just add a `<td>content</td>` everytime you get a new entry from your backend.

So your js would be something like this:

```js
function addRow(entry) {
  const el = document.getElementById('table');
  el.innerHTML += `<tr><td class="appear">${entry}</td></tr>`;
}

// if you use a websocket for example:
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8080');
ws.on('dataentry', (entry) => {
  addRow(entry);
});
```

and this your css:

```css
.appear {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0);
  transition: color;
  animation-name: appearAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes appearAnimation {
  from {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
  }
  to {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

html:

```html
<table id="table">
</table>
```

This code basically listens to a websocket on 'dataentry' event, then calls addRow which adds a row to the table with some example data.

If anything is unclear, write a comment!